# Ошибка при отправке письма с сайта

Tags: email

При отправке письма с сайта, если письмо отправляется на почтовый ящик на gmail, то письмо приходит без проблем, если отправлять письмо на ящик на mail.ru, то в почту приходит следующее сообщение об ошибке
[image]

проблема в настройках хостинга, я правильно понимаю? Подскажите, в чем может быть дело.

Comment: у меня возможно подобное было с аттачами на одном хостинге. хидеры были верные, но вместо аттача шел base64 код. Проблема была в способе обновления скрипта на сайте: обновляли через редактор текста в панели. вот этот редактор вместо \r\n ставил \n\n. посмотри, возможно подобная причина у тебя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уважаемый, советую глянуть доки для отправки почты на костыльный mail.ru

[Технические и административные требования для отправки электронных сообщений на Mail.Ru](http://help.mail.ru/mail-help/rules/technical)

Comment: спасибо, но поддержка хостинга уже решила проблему

Comment: В будущем всё равно пригодится. Просто mail.ru более требователен к правильным параметрам.